# How to make a task run in the background in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I have a music app that streams audio online. The only problem is it gets killed every time I exit the app which is not good for the user. They need it to keep running in the background even after exiting. How can I achieve this?

Comment: [they are working on it](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/3671)

Comment: Do u find anyway?

Comment: no not yet. you can try @RaoufRahiche solution

Answer (score 4):

[**Can I run Dart code in the background of an Flutter app?**](https://flutter.io/faq/#can-i-run-dart-code-in-the-background-of-an-flutter-app)

> Yes, you can run Dart code in a background process on both iOS and Android. For more information, see the [Medium article Executing Dart in the Background with Flutter Plugins and Geofencing](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124).