# How to make "Touch to return to call" with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, agora.io

I am using `agora.io` to create a calling app. It's possible to talk when the app starts, but once you close the app the call will end. With Facebook Messenger, Skype, and whatsAPPp, you can use other apps while keeping a call. What should I use to keep the app running in the background like this?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does agora.io support background call in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59815716/does-agora-io-support-background-call-in-flutter)

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I'm facing the same.

Comment: I found. 
> Your application can still run the voice call when it is switched to the background if the background mode is enabled. Select the app target in Xcode, click the Capabilities tab, enable Background Modes, and check Audio, AirPlay, and Picture in Picture.
https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtc_engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because when you close your app, iOS framework terminates the app process. to continue call with app in background you need to integrate some background service in app.
You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50790299/11445644) answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's because,the ios terminates process of the app.you can call with app in background you have to change some settings