# How to use Flutter Method Channel in background (app minimised/closed)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-plugin, flutter-method-channel

I am working on a native Android widget in a Flutter App. In which there is refresh button, on click of that I have to call a method in the Flutter code. I am using Flutter Method Channel for the communication and it is working fine when app is in foreground. But it does not work when app is minimised or closed. I get error **PlatformException(NO_ACTIVITY, null, null)**. Below is my code.

Android (AppWidgetProvider)

```
if (methodChannel == null && context != null) {
        FlutterMain.startInitialization(context)
        FlutterMain.ensureInitializationComplete(context, arrayOf())

        // Instantiate a FlutterEngine.
        val engine = FlutterEngine(context.applicationContext)

        // Define a DartEntrypoint
        val entrypoint: DartEntrypoint = DartEntrypoint.createDefault()

        // Execute the DartEntrypoint within the FlutterEngine.
        engine.dartExecutor.executeDartEntrypoint(entrypoint)

        // Register Plugins when in background. When there
        // is already an engine running, this will be ignored (although there will be some
        // warnings in the log).
        //GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(engine)

        methodChannel = MethodChannel(engine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, MainActivity.CHANNEL)
}

methodChannel!!.invokeMethod("fetchNewData", "", object : MethodChannel.Result {
        override fun notImplemented() {
            Toast.makeText(context, "method not implemented", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun error(errorCode: String?, errorMessage: String?, errorDetails: Any?) {
            Toast.makeText(context, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun success(result: Any?) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
})
```

Flutter

```
/// calling in main
static Future<void> attachListeners() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    var bloc = new AqiCnDashboardBloc();
    _channel.setMethodCallHandler((call) {
      switch (call.method) {
        case 'fetchNewData':
          bloc.getAqiCn(false);
          return null;
        default:
          throw MissingPluginException('notImplemented');
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: you can use the help of  [Work Manager Api](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) which works for handling background events even the app is closed

Comment: @KrishBhanushali Its not about background events only. The problem is how to use method channel (expects a foreground activity) in background.

Comment: @KrishBhanushali tried WorkManager plugin. Same error is happening.

Answer (score 5):

I am collecting information/discussion that redirects us to run flutter engine in background.

```
void callbackDispatcher() {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
print("Our background job ran!");
```

}

```
void main() {

 static const MethodChannel _channel = const MethodChannel("channel-name");

 Future<void> initialize(final Function callbackDispatcher) async {

  final callback = PluginUtilities.getCallbackHandle(callbackDispatcher);

 await _channel.invokeMethod('initialize', callback.toRawHandle());
 }
}
```

As stated here [How to run Flutter in the background?](https://medium.com/vrt-digital-studio/flutter-workmanager-81e0cfbd6f6e)

When a background job is started by native the Flutter engine is not active. So we are unable to run Dart.
Can Android/iOS starts the Flutter engine in the background?
Yes! We’ll first need to register a Dart callback function which will only be invoked whenever a background job is started by the native code.
This callback function is referred to as a callbackDispatcher.

Also please check out these stackoverflow discussions.

[Flutter : Run an app as a background service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51539893/flutter-run-an-app-as-a-background-service/59057145#59057145)

[How to create a service in Flutter to make an app to run always in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50106844/how-to-create-a-service-in-flutter-to-make-an-app-to-run-always-in-background)

[How to create a Flutter background service that works also when app closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62198049/how-to-create-a-flutter-background-service-that-works-also-when-app-closed)

[Executing Dart in the Background with Flutter Plugins and Geofencing](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124)

Comment: I have already gone through these articles. Can you post the code ?

Answer (score 0):

You may start the Flutter Engine in the background by register a Dart callback function which will only be invoked whenever a background job is started in Flutter.

Try this.
https://medium.com/vrt-digital-studio/flutter-workmanager-81e0cfbd6f6e