# Back ground process in flutter

Tags: flutter

Call a function in a background while app is background or terminated in flutter ,i tried background_fetch 1.0.1 package it doesnot worlk for me ,kindly help on this TIA

Comment: Hey @Amicus, check this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62198049/how-to-create-a-flutter-background-service-that-works-also-when-app-closed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a Flutter background service that works also when app closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62198049/how-to-create-a-flutter-background-service-that-works-also-when-app-closed)